# hide the borders for the mobile devices

Tags: html, css, border

I want to  hide the right border for the small width devices.

Please check the snippet.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #d {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; border-right:solid #8d989a 1px;height:230px;" id="d">
  <img src="vector-smart-object1.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #d {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #8d989a;height:230px;" id="d">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
</div>
```

Changes:
border-right:solid #8d989a 1px; ====> border-right: 1px solid #8d989a;
Added space before `id` keyword which was not there before editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the syntax of your `border-right` properties is wrong.
You should change it like so : `border-right : 1px solid #8d989a;`, because currently even with bigger screen it doesn't display the border.

Be carefull with parameters order in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with it a bit and figured out it needed @media only screen.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #d {
    border-right: 1px solid #8d989a;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;height:230px;" id="d">
     <img src="vector-smart-object1.png">
</div>
```

Here is a code pen showing this works.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayWVQG

Cheers

Comment: What device are you trying to view it on?

Comment: i just want to hide the border for small width screen

Answer (score 0):

You can detect mobile devices using http://mobiledetect.net. And change `border-right:solid #8d989a 1px;` to `border-right:1px solid #8d989a;`

```
     <div style="text-align:center;<?php if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {echo'border-right:1px solid #8d989a;';}?> height:230px;"id="d">
     <img src="vector-smart-object1.png" >      
 </div>
```